# Bootstrap 4 navbar-expand-* with custom breakpoints not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap navbar defined like this:

```html
<div class="container-fluid bg-secondary">
  <nav class="navbar utep-nav  navbar-inverse navbar-expand-lg">

    <button class="ut-toggler navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse  " id="navbarSupportedContent">

      <ul class="navbar-nav bg-secondary">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Products
                            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu bg-secondary">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Product 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Product 2</a>

            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I've overridden the default breakpoints as follows:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 1250px,
  xl: 1365px
) ;
```

I've tested the custom breakpoints and they seem to be working properly with .d-block .d-*-none. However, the "navbar-expand-lg" is not working as I expected. The navbar is still expanding at 992px (the default bootstrap value) instead of 1250px as I defined it above.

How can I make the navbar expand at 1250px instead of the default 992px?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it. I'm leaving it here in case someone else runs into this.

I added a new breakpoint to the variable as follows:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  force-menu-break: 1249.9px, //This will be rounded to 1250 by most screens.
  lg: 1250px,
  xl: 1365px
) ;
```

Then, I added the new class"navbar-expand-force-menu-break" to my navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar utep-nav  navbar-inverse navbar-expand-force-menu-break">
```

It's a workaround that works.